# Facebook Login Auth PHP BUG

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

We are using PHP to integrate a Facebook login system into our website. We have noticed a problem, we don't know whether it is a facebook bug or a bug on our side.
the scenario is that when a user clicks login with facebook, the facebook asks for permissions for the first time after logging in. if the user presses cancel on the permissions page then it is redirected to our website, if the user again clicks on the login with facebook button and then again cancels the permission the page instead of redirecting to our website , redirects to facebook.com.
Does anyone have any suggestions? is this a facebook bug?
you can see the issue on http://test.brightspyre.com by logging in.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's intended behaviour to stop loops of the auth dialog, it's not a bug - you shouldn't re-prompt the user for the same permissions multiple times in succession - bring them to an error page explaining why you needed the permissions, if the description in the auth dialog itself wasn't sufficient

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i am not prompting the user again for the permissions. the case is that when a user press cancel on the auth dialog multiple times then the auth dialog redirects to facebook instead of redirecting to our website.